# Are MySQL connections established with a deleted user still valid?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In MySQL, if a connection has been established successfully and then the user used to establish the connection is deleted does the connection remain valid?

What about Postgres and MS SQL Server?

The motivation for this question is the automatic rotation of credentials in an AWS secrets manager in the presence of connection pooling.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.

I created a user, connected to the DB, and performed some queries.

Then I dropped the user in another window.

I went back to the first window, the user was still able to perform queries until I disconnected. When I tried to reconnect, I got an error.

This was with local MySQL 5.x on a Linux server, I assume it's the same on RDS.

Comment: Thinking on it I wondered if this wouldn't be a security hole.  Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: It's a common optimization. Unix does the same thing: file permissions are only checked when a file is opened, not on every operation.

Comment: It also lets you rotate the password without disrupting existing connections. If you revoke the access granted to the user, then that should have effect immediately.